# How to make custom help for each page in SharePoint 2013 site?

Tags: sharepoint

We have SharePoint site with a lot of pages. One step in our project development is creating custom help for each page. After a user clicks "Help" icon in top of each page, help page opens and shows only that page's help content.

I know SharePoint have built-in help and users can customize it.
How can I customize SharePoint help desk to do this for each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create a normal pages library that has an extra field which is a URL of the page that you want this help page to be associated with.

On clicking the help icon, get the current page URL, search in the pages library where the URL field is equal to the current URL, then open a dialog or redirect to this page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I conclude from this sentence "get the current page URL, search in the pages library" 
that we need to develop helping pages. I want to use built in help in sharepoint. Is there any way to customize sharepoint help center?